# pinvoke from vb.net using structs in call

Tags: c++, vb.net, pinvoke, struct

I'm really struggling with the following pinvoke call.  I've tried numerous different ways of doing this but still no joy.

The call runs through, but I get a 'Bad parameter' message back with suggests there is something wrong with the struct, since I've ran through a c++ example of this code and the parameters are all correct.

I'd be so grateful for any help, I've googled myself mad already!

in the c++ header file:

```
int __stdcall DVSNET_OpenChannel(HANDLE hServer,unsigned long nChannel,DVSNET_CHANNEL_INFO *pChannelInfo,HANDLE *phChannel);

typedef struct tagDVSNET_CHANNEL_INFO
{
    unsigned long lStructSize;
    unsigned long dwStreamNo;
    unsigned long nProtocol;
    HWND          hWndDisplay;
    unsigned long bPlayStart;
    unsigned long dwBackFrameCount;
    unsigned long dwFlag;
} DVSNET_CHANNEL_INFO;
```

My definitions for the import:

```
<DllImport("DVSNETClient.dll")> _
Public Shared Function DVSNET_OpenChannel(ByVal hServer As System.IntPtr, ByVal nChannel As UInteger, ByRef pChannelInfo As IntPtr, ByRef phChannel As IntPtr) As Integer
End Function

<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
Public Structure tagDVSNET_CHANNEL_INFO
    Public lStructSize As UInteger
    Public dwStreamNo As UInteger
    Public nProtocol As UInteger
    Public hWndDisplay As IntPtr
    Public bPlayStart As UInteger
    Public dwBackFrameCount As UInteger
    Public dwFlag As UInteger
End Structure
```

My Calling code:

```
Private Sub OpenChannel()
    Dim intRet As Integer
    Dim ChannelInfo As New tagDVSNET_CHANNEL_INFO

    Dim HWD As New System.IntPtr

    ChannelInfo.lStructSize = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(ChannelInfo)
    ChannelInfo.nProtocol = 0
    ChannelInfo.dwStreamNo = 0
    ChannelInfo.dwBackFrameCount = 10
    ChannelInfo.hWndDisplay = HWD
    ChannelInfo.bPlayStart = 0 ' dont display
    'Channelinfo.dwFlag = 

    ' Initialize unmanged memory to hold the struct.
    Dim ptr As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(ChannelInfo))
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.StructureToPtr(ChannelInfo, ptr, True)

    Dim nChannel As UInteger = 1
    intRet = TotemPoleLib.DVSNET_OpenChannel(hServer, nChannel, ptr, hChannel)

    '... snip ...
End Sub
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know VB.Net syntax, but if you understand C# then here are the proper P/Invoke declarations for `DVSNET_CHANNEL_INFO` and `DVSNET_OpenChannel`:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct DVSNET_CHANNEL_INFO
{
    uint   lStructSize;
    uint   dwStreamNo;
    uint   nProtocol;
    IntPtr hWndDisplay;
    uint   bPlayStart;
    uint   dwBackFrameCount;
    uint   dwFlag;
}

static class DVSNETClient
{
    [DllImport("DVSNETClient.dll")]
    public static extern int DVSNET_OpenChannel(
        IntPtr hServer,
        uint nChannel,
        ref DVSNET_CHANNEL_INFO pChannelInfo,
        ref IntPtr phChannel
    );
}
```

Your `DVSNET_CHANNEL_INFO` appears fine, but the 3rd argument of `DVSNET_OpenChannel` should simply be a `ref DVSNET_CHANNEL_INFO`; all the marshaling is done for you automatically, no real need for the `Marshal` class here. The **only** thing you need to do is initialize `ChannelInfo.lStructSize` to the value of `Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(DVSNET_CHANNEL_INFO))` before calling `DVSNET_OpenChannel`. It would probably be sensible to do this in a non-default constructor for `DVSNET_CHANNEL_INFO`, but given that it's a struct, there is of course no way to enforce use of that constructor over the implicit default constructor.

Note that semantically it's possible that `pChannelInfo` and/or `phChannel` should be `out` rather than `ref`, but it's not possible to tell by the signature of `DVSNET_OpenChannel`. In any case, using `ref` will work regardless, though it will be less efficient than using `out` if `out` is indeed warranted.

Comment: fantastic, that works a treat thanks!  -I thought I'd already tried this before changing the structure to ptr method, but obviously got something wrong along the way.  Many thanks again!